# JAX-WS web service : Beans not injected : NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have developed a JAX-WS based web-service. I have Web service layer, service layer and a Dao layer. When i call a service method from web service class it gives null pointer exception. The reason is the service class bean is not getting injected.

**web-service class:**

```
package com.test.webservice.controller;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.test.salary.service.SalaryService;

@WebService
public class EmployeeSalaryWebService {

    private SalaryService salaryService;


    /**
     * @param salaryService the salaryService to set
     */
     @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setSalaryService(SalaryService salaryService) {
        this.salaryService = salaryService;
    }


    @WebMethod
    public double getEmployeeSalary(String name){

        System.out.println("==== Inside getEmployee Salary === "+salaryService );
        return salaryService.calculateSalary(name);
    }
}
```

**Application-context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="salaryWebService"
        class="com.test.webservice.controller.EmployeeSalaryWebService">
        <property name="salaryService" ref="salaryService" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="salaryService" class="com.test.salary.service.SalaryServiceImpl">
        <property name="salaryDAO" ref="salaryDAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="salaryDAO" class="com.test.salary.dao.SalaryDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="LOCAL" />
        <property name="password" value="abcdef" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/salaryConfiguration.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Please let me know why the **SalaryService salaryService** not getting injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service class and bean in context is two separate things. I believe that you don't get bean from context and just use class, aren't you?
I advice you marking your service class with

```
@Component
```

That will make your class to become spring bean.
Then you can use inside following annotation.

```
@Autowired
```

This will try to find appropriate bean with annotated element type in spring context.
 And don't forget to put into your context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
```

This will search all classes marked as @Component and add it to spring context as beans.
For more detailed instruction you can check this article
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/jaxws-with-spring-and-maven-tutorial.html

Comment: i followed the article , it worked. Now need to understand how it all works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make your SalaryService auto wired as follows:

```
public class EmployeeSalaryWebService {

@Autowired
private SalaryService salaryService;
....
```